Irreducibility over Field extensions.
This is part of something bigger that I'm trying to prove, but I'm having difficulties with this part, which seems like it should be relatively simple.
The polynomial $(x^2 - p)$, $p$ prime, is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ by Eisenstein's criterion. Considering the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, ..., \sqrt{p_{k-1}})$, we can show that $\sqrt{p_k}$ (the k-th prime) $\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, ..., \sqrt{p_{k-1}})$. Thus, $(x^2 - p_k)$ has no root and, as it has degree 2, it is irreducible.
Now, the polynomial $(x^n - p)$, $n \geq 4$, is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. How do I demonstrate that it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, ..., \sqrt{p_{k-1}})$ (or something analogous, considering the nth roots)? Since the degree of the polynomial is greater than 3, having no root does not imply irreducibility. It seems straightforward that this extension does not contribute anything to make the polynomial reducible, but I am not able to demonstrate it rigorously.
PS: Eisenstein's criterion is applied to polynomials within polynomial rings over fields using primes from associated integral domains, right? If it makes sense to apply this reasoning, how do we deal with the notion of primes in this case?

This argument only works for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, ..., \sqrt{p_{k-1}})$. It uses concepts from algebraic number theory, which you may or may not have studied.
Note that $p$ is unramified in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{q})$ for $p \neq q$ distinct primes and $p$ odd. Thus assuming that $p>p_{k-1}$, $p$ is also unramified in the composite field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, ..., \sqrt{p_{k-1}})$ (See here). Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, ..., \sqrt{p_{k-1}})}$ above $p$. Then because $p$ is unramified, we get that $p\notin \mathfrak{p}^2$. Therefore, we can apply Eisenstein in the ring given by the localization of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, ..., \sqrt{p_{k-1}})}$ at $\mathfrak{p}$, which is a PID, to get irreducibility.
The general idea is this: if $f \in \Bbb Z[x]$ is $p$-Eisenstein, then it is irreducible over any number field in which $p$ is unramified, because it will still be Eisenstein there with respect to some (any) prime ideal above $p$.
The same kind of argument works for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]{2},\sqrt[n]{3}, \ldots, \sqrt[n]{p_{k-1}})$ as long as $p$ does not divide $n$, due to a computation of the discriminant, which implies that if $p$ does not divide $n$ and $p \neq q$, then $p$ is unramified in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]{q})$.

Thank you very much for the answer! I haven't gotten to that part about ramification yet, but I will definitely take a look. I ended up finding a way to show what I wanted. Unfortunately, it goes over the number of characters allowed in this answer.
